# How to identify if a function was called recursivly in R

Tags: r, recursion

The title says it all.

**Example:**

```
f <- function(x, r = TRUE) {

  out <- x + 10

  if(r) {
    out2 <- f(x, r = FALSE)
  }
  # Here I want something like:
  # if(f_was_called_recursively) {
  #   # only return out
  #   out
  # } else if(!f_was_called_recursively) { 
  #   # return the result from the recursive AND the 
  #   # non recursive calls if an recursive call has been made (if r = TRUE)
  #   if(r) {
  #   out <- list("outer" = out, "inner" = out2)
  #   } else {
  #   out <- list("outer" = out, "inner" = NA)
  #   }
  # }
  # out
}
```

**Problem:** 
How can I get this `f_was_called_recursively`?

Comment: Not too sure what the commented out part does. Are you trying to write a stopping condition for the recursion?

Comment: No the background is this: f is a function that performs bootstrapping. Sometimes I need to bootstrap from a bootstrap sample, hence the recursion. In essence, I need to output one thing if the “inner” function is called and another for the “outer”